# How does Azure's DnsManagementClient work with MSI? (AzureServiceTokenProvider)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-management-api, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to update a TXT record in azure.  I'm doing this in my local VS2017 debugging environment, but MSI seems to "work" anyway, because it knows who I am.  But the "GetAsync" call fails telling me I don't have permission.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var tokenprovider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var tok = await tokenprovider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/");
client = new DnsManagementClient(new TokenCredentials(tok)) 
{ 
    SubscriptionId = SubscriptionId 
};
var dnsRecord = await Client.RecordSets.GetAsync(ResourceGroup, zoneName, recordName, RecordType.TXT, cancellationToken);
```

The GetAsync call throws:
**Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: 'The client '(my email address)' with object id '(my object id)' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/TXT/read' over scope '/subscriptions/(my subscription id)/resourceGroups/(my resource group)/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/(my domain)/TXT/_acme-challenge'.'**

Any idea why?

I've given myself contributor access to the TXT record.  I even did this whole thing as the subscription owner.  Yet I still get the exception telling me I'm not authorized.

I've also double-checked the subscription/object/domain/txt names - they are correct.

Help :)

EDIT:  After a "waiting period" of a while, the calls suddenly started to succeed.  So to test... I made a new resource, tried to access it (and failed), gave myself access, tried to access it again (and failed again), and then waited a while and tried later, and it succeeded.  Any idea why this could be?

EDIT: (5 months later).  Found the correct answer, which is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/troubleshooting#rbac-changes-are-not-being-detected

There is up to 30 minutes delay when fiddling with role assignments before they take effect.

Answer (score 0):

well, sorry, but you dont have permissions to do what you are doing :) one way to check you are who you think you are is do something like:

```
Get-AzAdUser -ObjectId <id_from_error>
```

and verify that you are getting back the same user. another thing worth checking is permission ;) maybe you gave rights to another entity by mistake

Comment: One possibility is wrong Azure AD tenant. In local dev you have to sometimes tell AzureServiceTokenProvider what tenant to use.

Comment: I am 100% sure that I have permissions